# What is the pure speech in Zephaniah 3:9?

Tags: john, luke

Zephaniah 3 English Standard Version

> 9 “For at that time I will change the speech of the peoples to a **pure speech**, that all of them may call upon the name of the LORD and serve him with one accord.
> 10From beyond the rivers of Cush
> my worshipers, the daughter of my dispersed ones,
> shall bring my offering.

Is this about one common human worshipping language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note some alternate versions that throw more light on Zeph 3:9

**New International Version**
"Then I will purify the lips of the peoples, that all of them may call on the name of the LORD and serve him shoulder to shoulder.

**New American Standard Bible**
"For then I will give to the peoples purified lips, That all of them may call on the name of the LORD, To serve Him shoulder to shoulder.

**Christian Standard Bible**
For I will then restore pure speech to the peoples so that all of them may call on the name of the LORD and serve him with a single purpose.

**Contemporary English Version**
I will purify each language and make those languages acceptable for praising me. Then, with hearts united, everyone will serve only me, the LORD.

This is part of a more general pattern of scripture that suggests that our sins separate us from God:

> Isa 59:2 - But your iniquities have separated you from your God; your
> sins have hidden his face from you, so that he will not hear.

> 1 Peter 3:7 - Husbands, in the same way be considerate as you live
> with your wives, and treat them with respect as the weaker partner and
> as heirs with you of the gracious gift of life, so that nothing will
> hinder your prayers.

Thus, sinfulness separates from God, Isa 59:2, Gal 5:4, Eph 2:12, Ps 22:1, Eze 14:5, Jer 6:8.

In Zeph 3:9 we are discussing the problem of lies and the need to restore truthfulness - pure speech is necessary to be honest with God as declared in this verse.  Sinners, by definition, are not serving God.  Thus, God promises to restore and reconcile us (2 Cor 5:18, 19) by purifying us so that we can serve Him with a pure heart, 1 Tim 1:5, 2 Tim 2:22, Ps 24:4, 51:10, Matt 5:8, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Both Young's Literal and Green's Literal demonstrate a different meaning to the verse.

> For then will I change to the peoples a lip clear to call all of them by the name of Jehovah to serve him ... [Zephaniah 3:9 Green's Literal]

> For then do I turn unto peoples a pure lip to call all of them by the name of Jehovah ...
> [Zephaniah 3:9 YLT]

Each of these translators is expressing that fact that it is Jehovah who will call peoples by his name, not that the people, as such, will call upon himself. Not that such would not do so, of course, just that these two translators are conveying that the text does not state that.

The prophecy is like many visionary expressions in scripture where the seer sees two things, one a backdrop against which another vision is viewed. Sometimes the present situation is seen in the foreground against a background of future occurrence and one has to see what the prophet saw in order to distinguish the two.

The 'Little Apocalypse' is one example, Matthew 24, 25.

But here the backdrop is one of judgment ('... that I may assemble the kingdoms to pour upon them my indignation... [KJV]) and in the foreground is the promise of another people with a pure language.

I am reminded of Isaiah confessing his uncleanness and his being purged with a coal from off the altar that touched his lips. Only then, thereafter, is he owned of the Lord and sent.

Only when there is truth in the mouth does the Lord own his people and call them by his own name.

> Speak ye every man the truth to his neighbour ... and love no false oath ... for all these things do I hate, saith the Lord. [Zechariah 8:16,17 KJV]

> Wherefore putting away lying, speak every man truth with his neighbour : for we are members one of another. [Ephesians 4:25 KJV]

> Wherefore come out from among them, and be ye separate, saith the Lord, and touch not the unclean thing; and I will receive you and be a Father to you, and ye shall be my sons and my daughters, saith the Lord Almighty. [2 Corinthians 6:17,18 KJV]